# Finding values and duplicates in large JSON dataset with python

Tags: python, json, data-structures

I have a huge data set (B) of JSON objects. I have another smaller data set (A) of JSON objects as well. What is the **fastest** way to see if every element in A is within B? Also how would I check if there are duplicates of elements in A that are in B?

What I had in mind was creating a `dictionary` of the data set B with its key value pair being the same JSON value. This will allow for fast lookups. I will do the same thing for set A as well however the value for each key in set A will be an empty list.

With each key in set A will be looked up on set B and appended to the respective list. Once this is done, the length of the list will determine if any of these values are not found, matched, duplicated.

If the length of the list for a key in set A is

```
0  --> none found in B
1  --> 1 found in B
>1 --> more than one found in B (duplicates found)
```

I dont think standard dictionaries support duplicates, not really sure which data structure to use to support duplicate key, value pairs

Comment: Have you considered using set's intersection and difference methods? like set(B).intersection(A), where A and B are your dictionaries. For the duplicates, I think you should take care of them at the time of creating you dictionary from your JSON data.

Comment: @user2757226 thank you for bringing this up! I cannot set(B) because I need to prove that there are duplicates

Comment: How about a single dict with key being the json value and value being a list of [A_count, B_count]? Depending on what the json data is, you may need a way to normalize the data. Lists and dicts can't be keys. You could for instance, turn a dict into a sorted tuple of (key,value) tuples.

Comment: @tdelaney I am not quite sure what you are trying to say sorry =/

Comment: @Liondancer. Your question is severely underspecified. How do you determine which objects are duplicates? How is comparison of the objects to be done? What do you intend to use as the keys of the dictionaries? Do you have any control over the creation of the JSON files and/or the objects they contain?

Comment: @Liondancer, I guess I should start with a more basic question, what do the json objects look like? Do you plan to deserialize them into python objects or just use the serialized json strings.  If you deserialize, do they contain unhashable objects like dicts and lists?

Comment: @tdelaney I havent yet planned that far yet because I wanted to get a generally idea of what my plan of action is. But I think my first approach would be to have serialized JSON Strings as keys and values for set B and serialized JSON string for set A as the keys and empty lists as values. When a key from set A is found in set B, set B's value will be appended to set A's list

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's a best guess. It uses dicts instead of json objects, so you'll want to double check that the comparison works in your case. This uses a generator to make tuples of (object, count). If there are 0 instances of `obj` in in B, False gets inserted. Then, it checks to see if False is there, to satisfy:

> see if every element in A is within B

I don't know if it's the fastest way, but its what I came up with off the top of my head. A and B are lists of dicts, in this case, just pairs of `{'a':'a'}` for testing. Play with the slices at the end to see if it meets your requirements.

List A contains every other letter and list B contains letters from D-Z.

```
import string

a = [{x:x} for x in list(string.ascii_lowercase)[0:26:2]] # Every other letter                                                                               
b = [{x:x} for x in list(string.ascii_lowercase)[3:26]]

def compare(a, b):
    for obj in a:
        c = b.count(obj)
        if c == 0:
            yield False # Every element in A is not in B                                                                                                     
        yield (obj, c)


findings = [res for res in compare(a,b)]
print findings

if False in findings:
    print "Every element of A is not in B"
else:
    for res in findings:
        obj, num = res
        print "Object %s was found %d times" % (str(obj), num)
```

If you don't need the counts, you can change the compare function to:

```
def compare2(a, b):
    for obj in a:
        if b.count(obj) == 0:
            return False
    return True
```